# Re-declaring variables in loops

Tags: loops

In case i have a code this way:

```
int n = // some arbitrary number
while (n--)
{
  int t=0;
  // do somethings here
}
```

Does the variable `t` take up another space `while (n--)`. That is, if on first run `t` takes cell A0, on the second run, does it take cell A1, then A2 and so on... eating up the memory cells?

PS. this is in the case of "non-garbage-collecting" languages like C, C++

Answer (score 0):

Generalization at the risk of oversimplification--

If you view this your example in terms of scope, then there is one allocation at procedure startup. The braces merely restart the scope of t to within the braces.

If you view this in terms of creation and destruction, each { in the loop iteration create a new t but each } deletes it.

In none of these models does the loop create repeated memory usage.